# Eigenvalues of circulant like matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutation-matrices

Let $q$ be a positive integer and let $P$ be the $p \times p$ permutation matrix given by $P(e_i)=e_{i+q}$, where the indices are mod $p$. Let $v$ be a column vector. What are, and how to compute, the eigenvalues of the matrix $M=[v,Pv,P^2v,\dots , P^{p-1}v]$?
An answer with $p$ prime and $q \leq p$ would be great.

Comment: Would a permutation of the columns of $M$ be a circulant matrix?

Comment: Yes I do not see how this cold help

Comment: If $q=1$, isn't $M$ circulant?

Comment: I would change the notation and use $d$ instead of $p$.  Let the matrix be $d \times d$ and let $p_{ij}$ be its $i,j$-th entry.